# Is it possible to redefine what Keynote interprets as bold and normal for a particular font?

Tags: keynote, font

When working in Keynote I like to use medium and light fonts instead of bold and normal. This causes me a problem because when I hit apple-b to embolden something I want the font to be switched to medium instead of bold, but the default is the bold font. Is there someway for me to either a) redefine what a particular presentation interprets as bold and normal or b) assign a different shortcut key to switch the font between medium and light?

**UPDATE:** An option c) occurs to me too: could I copy the whole font somehow and play around with its definition to replace normal with light and bold with medium?

Comment: c) Yes, but font editing software is expensive, and fonts are a particularly fragile file format.

Comment: Exactly, what @phillip said. You can play around with a font, but you might end up causing more trouble than anything else.

Comment: OK, thanks. If I'm ever feeling a little foolhardy I might give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer directly to your two questions:

a) No, you can’t redefine what is bold and what is normal as far as I know, Medium and Light are different styles than Regular and Bold and there isn’t a keyboard shortcut to set them (nor a menu item for that) and because of the latter, you can’t set a keyboard shortcut.

b) Because of (a), you can’t really do this.

A (lame) alternative is to use Copy Style <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and paste style <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. But that requires that you find a piece of text that has the same size/font.

Also having the Formatting bar visible makes it easier (albeit with the mouse) to change that: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Yup, it was (a) that seemed like the stumbling block to me too. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: I find it very odd that it’s not possible, but I haven’t found a way. :(